# check if the radio button clicked is the answer stored in database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am designing an online test series. I want when an answer is selected by the user, it should be validated by the answer stored in the database and move to next question on the basis of correct and incorrect choice. I am using php and mysqli. Can someone tell me how to get the id of the user selected answer and validate with the correct answer? This is html

```
<form method="POST" name="try" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">;
        <h4> <?php echo $_SESSION["Question"] ?> </h4>
        <input type="radio" name="options" value="A" id="A"> <?php echo $_SESSION["OpA"] ?> </input><br>
        <input type="radio" name="options" value="B" id="B"> <?php echo $_SESSION["OpB"] ?> </input><br>
        <input type="radio" name="options" value="C" id="C"> <?php echo $_SESSION["OpC"] ?> </input><br>
        <input type="radio" name="options" value="D" id="D"> <?php echo $_SESSION["OpD"] ?> </input><br>
        <input type="radio" name="options" value="E" id="E"> <?php echo $_SESSION["OpE"] ?> </input><br>
        <button type="button" class="btn" name="submit" value="submit" >Submit</button>
    <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
        mysqli_select_db( $conn , 'myDB' );
        echo "<form method='get' action=" .htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . ";>";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM QUANT_MEDIUM ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0)      
        {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
                $_SESSION['ans'] = $row['Correct'];
                $_SESSION['Question'] = $row['Ques'];
                $_SESSION['OpA'] = $row['Option_A'];
                $_SESSION['OpB'] = $row['Option_B'];
                $_SESSION['OpC'] = $row['Option_C'];
                $_SESSION['OpD'] = $row['Option_D'];
                $_SESSION['OpE'] = $row['Option_E'];

            }
        }
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']) and ! empty($_POST['submit']))
{
    if (isset($_POST['options'])) 
    {
        $radio_input = $_POST['options'];
        echo $radio_input;
    }
}
else 
{
    echo "wrong";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before looking at a possible solution you must determine where you want the check to be done. You tagged the question "jquery" so I guess you're interested in a clientside option as well as a serverside option.

**Client side**
If you want to do the check clientside, depending on how you implement it, the user might be able to see the correct answer by inspecting the code. If this is no problem, you can have the fastest user experience by checking it clientside.

The most simple option, but easy to "hack" would be to add an extra attribute to the radiobutton. Something like "correct" or so. When the submit button is clicked you can use jquery to check if the selected radio button has the "correct" attribute and do whatever action you want with that info.

You can also have the frontend do a query to the server to check. This would be more secure, but the method described above is the simplest.

**Server side** 
If you want the client to have no possible way of getting the answer beforehand, you're best doing the check serverside. Here the "onclick"you have on the submit button can be removed and have the form do an actual post to the server, and have the server do a check and display the next question if the given answer is correct. 
In order to have the server know what question is being checked you could add a hidden field with the question ID.

Comment: i was using the client side option, but as you said, it isn't secure. So i am shifting to server side. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to improve the user experience, you could use JS to check with the backend. 

The Js could display a loader animation while it does a call to your backend to check if the user answered correctly. Once it gets a response you can hide the loader animation and redirect to the next question or display an error message.

Comment: That is a great idea sir. Thanks a lot for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

The validation can be done on the server side using php. The solution would be not to use a submit button and let the server take the responsibility of checking what is submitted to the server. So the submit button can be replaced by the following :

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn"></input>
```

And the validation can be done using the following piece of code :

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) and ! empty($_POST['submit']))
        {
            if (isset($_POST['options'])) 
            {
                $radio_input = $_POST['options'];
                //echo $radio_input;
                if($radio_input == $_SESSION['ans'])
                    echo "correct";
                else
                    echo "incorrect";
            }
        }
?>
```